# Android playing mp3 songs from listview to another activity

Tags: android

Hello iam making a simple mp3 player before this i have implemented the media player in one activity
but now i have two activity in the first activity i have a listview and in the second activity i have seekbar and also play and pause buttons with an image for the song
but i dont have any idea that how i can implement this when a person click the song name in the listview from first activity it goes to second activity and play the song in the second activity with play, pause and seekbar
is there any source code or idea that i can check that, if i use putExtra so how i can send the index of songs from listview to second activity my mp3 files are in the raw folder, i have this code but this is for reading songs from external storage i want from raw folder

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
Boolean mExternalStorageAvailable;
String[] items;//to read all files
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 99;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkStoragePermission();
    }
}

public ArrayList<File> findSong(File root){
    ArrayList<File> at = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for(File singleFile : files){
        if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
            at.addAll(findSong(singleFile));
        }
        else{
            if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") ||
                    singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")){
                at.add(singleFile);
            }
        }
    }
    return at;
}


void display(){
    final ArrayList<File> mySongs =
            findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    items = new String[ mySongs.size() ];
    for(int i=0;i<mySongs.size();i++){
        //toast(mySongs.get(i).getName().toString());
        items[i] =  mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","").replace(".wav","");

    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new
            ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);
    listView.setAdapter(adp);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int
                position, long l) {
            startActivity(new
                            Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayerActivity.class).putExtra("pos",position).putExtra("songs",mySongs));

        }
    });
}


void checkExternalStorage(){
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    } else {
        mExternalStorageAvailable= false;
    }
    handleExternalStorageState();
}
void handleExternalStorageState() {
    if(mExternalStorageAvailable){
        display();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please insert an SDcard",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}


public boolean checkStoragePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new
                            String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new
                            String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[]
                                               grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    checkExternalStorage();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Second activity for playing songs

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static MediaPlayer mp;//assigning memory loc once or else multiple     songs will play at once

int position;
SeekBar sb;
ArrayList<File> mySongs;
Thread updateSeekBar;
Button pause,forward,reverse,next,previous;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
    forward = (Button)findViewById(R.id.forward);

    previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous);
    next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    reverse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reverse);
    sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);


    updateSeekBar=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            int currentPosition = 0;
            while(currentPosition < totalDuration){
                try{
                    sleep(500);
                    currentPosition=mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    sb.setProgress(currentPosition);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    if(mp != null){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
    position = b.getInt("pos",0);
    Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
    mp.start();
    sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
    updateSeekBar.start();
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new
                                          SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i,
                                                                            boolean b) {
                                              }
                                              @Override
                                              public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                              }
                                              @Override
                                              public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                                                  mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                                              }
                                          });
    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                pause.setText(">");
                mp.pause();

            }
            else {
                pause.setText("||");
                mp.start();
            }
        }
    });
    forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition()+5000);
        }
    });
    reverse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition()-5000);
        }
    });
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            position=((position+1)%mySongs.size());
            Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get( position).toString());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            position=((position-1)<0)?(mySongs.size()-1):(position-1);
            Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(
                    position).toString());//%mysongs so that it do not go to invalid  position

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to follow for the start.

1. Store the file names in arrayList using model class.
2. populate recyclerview using this model class
3. now implement recyclerview onClick
4. on click pass the file name to player Screen

Comment: thanks, do you have any simple code that i can see the implementation

Comment: i have edited the question i have some code but it is for external storage i want to play from raw folder